# Definition of morphism of elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am trying to understand the definition of a morphism of elliptic curves, and perhaps in doing so something about $\mathbb{P}^1$ as well. We say $\varphi:E_1\rightarrow E_2$ is a morphism from $E_1$ to $E_2$ if for every $P\in E_1$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $P$ such that $\varphi|_U(P)=[f_0(P):f_1(P):f_2(P)]$ for homogeneous $f_i\in\overline{F}[x_0,y_0,z_0]$ of the same degree.

My question is what does an open neighborhood of $\mathbb{P}^1$ even look like? Is there an implicit topology?

Comment: Yes, the Zariski topology.

Comment: Your elliptic curves are subvarieties of $\Bbb{P}^2$ not $\Bbb{P}^1$.  Do you see how a rational function $f\in \Bbb{C}(z)$ is a morphism $F:\Bbb{P}^1\to \Bbb{P}^1$ but not $\Bbb{C\to C}$ (when it is not a polynomial) ? Covering $\Bbb{P}^1$ by several affine charts ($\Bbb{C}-a-b$ is an affine subset of $\Bbb{P}^1$ because it comes with its ring of regular functions $\Bbb{C}[z,(z-a)^{-1},(z-b)^{-1}]$) we can define $F$ by gluing several affine morphisms. Then do the same for the morphism $E\to E :y^2=x^3+x,\varphi(P)=[2]P$.